# Как запретить ввод букв в числовое поле инпута в библиотеке Ant Design (React js)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, ant, ant-design

Пытаюсь настроить числовое поле инпута (InputNumber https://ant.design/components/input-number/) так, чтобы в него не вводились никакие символы и буквы, кроме цифр. Стандартное поведение инпута в библиотеке Ant Design (https://ant.design/): буквы вводятся, а при клике вне поля, все буквы пропадают и поле остаётся пустым. Встроенных пропсов у либы, отвечающих за поведение ввода в инпут не нашёл. Прошу помочь разобраться, вот изначальный мой код:

```
import React from "react";
import { observer } from "mobx-react";
import { NumberInput } from "components/uui/NumberInput/NumberInput";
import { BaseModel } from "models/BaseModel";
import classNames from "classnames";
import styles from "components/fields/styles.less";

interface Props {
  name: string;
  model: BaseModel;
  onChange?: (value: number) => void;
  autoFocus?: boolean;
  size?: "large" | "small";
  min?: number;
  className?: string;
  noLabel?: boolean;
  labelColor?: string;
  max?: number;
}

@observer
export class NumberField extends React.Component<Props> {
  static defaultProps = {
    min: 5,
    autoFocus: true,
    labelColor: "darkGray"
  };

  private handleInput = (value: number): void => {
    const { model, name, onChange } = this.props;
    model.setAttribute(name, value);

    if (onChange) {
      onChange(value);
    }
  };

  get value(): number {
    const { model, name } = this.props;

    // @ts-ignore
    // TODO: make it generic
    return model[name];
  }

  render(): React.ReactChild {
    const { className, model, noLabel, name, labelColor, ...rest } = this.props;

    return (
      <div className={classNames(styles.formField, className)}>
        {!noLabel && (
          <label className={styles[labelColor]}>{model.getLabel(name)}</label>
        )}
        <NumberInput value={this.value} onChange={this.handleInput} {...rest} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

По идее мне просто нужно не принимать никакие символы кроме цифр, в значении value, но мои варианты почему-то не работают. Если я правильно понимаю, то мне нужно написать в одну из этих функций проверку на число или replace:

```
private handleInput = (value: number): void => {
    const { model, name, onChange } = this.props;        
    model.setAttribute(name, value);

    if (onChange) {
      onChange(value);
    }
  };

  get value(): number {
    const { model, name } = this.props;

    // @ts-ignore
    // TODO: make it generic
    return model[name];
  }
```

Перепробовал кучу вариантов и ничего не работает...=(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В случае контролируемого инпута в обработчике события `handleInput` можно использовать обновлённое `value` в котором останутся только цифры:

```
const clearedValue = value.replace(/\D/g,'');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const InputNumber = React.forwardRef((ref, props) => {
   const { initialValue, onChange = null } = props;
   const [currentValue, setCurrentValue] = useState(initialValue);

   const handleChange = useCallback((event) => {
      const value = event.target.value.replace(/\D+/g, '');

      if (currentValue !== value) {
         setCurrentValue(value);
         
         if (onChange !== null) {
            onChange(event);
         }
      }

   }, [currentValue, onChange]);

   return (
      <Input
         {...props}
         ref={ref}
         onChange={onChange}
         value={currentValue}
      />
   );
});
```